# Nice way of assigning true or false to value in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I know that conditional value assignment to a variable can be done that way:

```
TEST="test"

if [[ $TEST="test" ]]
then
  VAR=true
else
  VAR=false
fi
```

But is there any other way to assign `true` or `false` value in bash, with nicer, more compact syntax?

Comment: `[[ true_condition ]]; VAR=$?`. True, `$?` is either 0 or 1 in this case, but `true` and `false` are just arbitrary strings, not Boolean values. How do you plan to *use* `VAR`?

Comment: Could you clarify what `true_condition` is supposed to be? It's meant to represent a condition like for example, `$foo == bar`, right? As written, Bash would interpret it as a string, which would make the `[[ ]]` always return true. In that case, you could just write `VAR=true` and not need any `if`. But that's probably too literal :) I ask partly because, if it's a math condition, you could do `VAR=$((true_condition))` and get either 0 or 1.

Comment: You forgot the spaces: `[[ $TEST = "test" ]]`

Comment: _Don't_ use strings `true` and `false`. It encourages running them as commands, and running variables as command leads to injection vulnerabilities. Much better to use numbers. If you use 0 for false and greater-than-zero for true, that allows `if (( variable )); then ...` syntax